# Auxiliary class to a custom library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a custom library `application\library\myLibrary\myLibrary.php` for codeigniter. The library requires a few auxiliary classes for internal working and also to return objects of these auxiliary classes to the calling function.

My question is, should I put these auxiliary classes in separate files in the same directory `application\library\myLibrary\auxilary.php` or should I keep them in the same file as the library class ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way. You can do it with your wish.

But when you calling that to controller you have to use the structure too.

> If **inside folder**(`library/foder_name/auxilary.php`)
>
> ```
> $this->load->library('foder_name/class_name');
> ```
>
> If **without sub-folder**(`library/auxilary.php`)
>
> ```
> $this->load->library('class_name');
> ```